# Chef - how to avoid duplicating a recipe

Tags: chef-infra

In our Chef cookbooks we support multiple versions of the same software. But we've adopted a bad practice. For each version we've made a copy of the recipe and changed it's attributes.

e.g.

```
remote_file install_file do
  source node['android']['sdk']['23']['source_url']
  not_if do
    ::File.exists?(extract_dir)
  end
  notifies :run, "execute[extract-sdk-23]", :immediately
end
```

becomes

```
remote_file install_file do
  source node['android']['sdk']['24']['source_url']
  not_if do
    ::File.exists?(extract_dir)
  end
  notifies :run, "execute[extract-sdk-24]", :immediately
end
```

This is essentially code duplication. It'd be cleaner to keep the attributes the same but vary their values.

Is this possible with Chef?

If it matters we use chef-client zero directly. i.e. We don't use knife, etc.

Comment: Don't really get your problem. You could have the version (`23`/`24`) also as an attribute. The name of the `"execute[extract-sdk-24]"` action could be composed using string concatenation, or if it's always the same, just name it `extract-sdk` (of what?).

Comment: You could also make that thing a [resource](https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources.html) to make your recipe even more cleaner.

Comment: @StephenKing Currently I can run different recipes by calling android::sdk_24 or android::sdk_23. I'm hoping to do the same but have only one recipe which runs with different attribute values. I'll need to look into resources to see if they're what I'm after.

Comment: If you want to be able to install both during the same chef run, create a resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @StephenKing mentioned, the best bet is probably to write a custom resource that abstracts the logic. You could also put all the different SDKs in a hash in the node attributes and then iterate over them in a single recipe, but this is going to be less flexible.